# Get records from DNS query

Tags: php, dns

Our current DNS provider is delivering terrible service, we have something like 300 domains at them and they can't deliver us BIND files or similar, that would allow us to move to another provider - automagically.

What I would like to do, is to create a script that will extract all records for a specific domain, A records, MX records, SRV TXT - all I can get hold of - from querying some DNS lookup.

I'm really out on a limb here - is this at all possible ?

Best wishes,
Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [DNS Lookup in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113638/dns-lookup-in-php)

Comment: Procure new DNS provider as secondary DNS. Have current provider add new provider as secondary.  Zone tranfer current to new.  Switch new to primary.  Voila.  I use rollernet.us.

Comment: Do you want the records from a specific DNS server or your default one?

Comment: AbraCadaver : The problem is current provider would be losing our business - they have no interest in helping us "escape", but nice touch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the records you can try :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

If you want it from a **specific** DNS server you can try :

http://www.purplepixie.org/phpdns/

Comment: Kunal : This would ofcourse do it for me, it looks like I never even bothered google it (I did though) - thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @mark.bjaergager You wanted the **specific** part, right ? And BTW Welcome :) I am always happy to help.